# Which of the following are quadratic integers in $Q[√−5]$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Which of the following are quadratic integers in $Q[√−5]$?

EDIT: THANKS TO THE COMMUNITY FOR DIRECTING ME TO THE ORIGINAL QUESTION! I DID NOT KNOW THIS QUESTION ALREADY EXISTED ON MATH.SE

(a) $3/5$

(b) $2 + 3√−5$

(c) $(3 + 8√−5)/2$

(d) $(3 + 8√−5)/5$

(e) $i√−5$

Prove your result in each case.

Here's what I've got so far (I'm not even sure if this is half  right):

$\{1,i\sqrt{5}\}$ forms a basis for the field  $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-5})$ viewed as a vector space over  $\mathbb{Q}$.
We note that,
$\mathbb{Q}\leq \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-5})$
Meaning, that the rationals are contained in this simple extension.

a)Yes, as just explained all rationals are contained in this field.

d)Yes, it is  $\frac{3}{5}+\frac{8}{5}\sqrt{-5}$ so if we select  $a=3/5$, $b=8/5$ in $\mathbb{Q}$ as a linear combination for  $a+b\sqrt{-5}$ then it works!

e)No, unless we are asking for  $i\sqrt{5}$.

I am having trouble on how to explain (b) and (c).

Comment: The ring of integers of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-5})$ is not a field, and it does not contain all rational numbers.

Comment: You need to review your definition of quadratic integer. In particular, a rational is a quadratic integer iff it is an integer.